# Google Analytics Campaigns Tracking in Chrome Store

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-analytics

We have an extension for Google Chrome released in the Chrome Store and we are using Google Analytics to get some metrics. All seems to work ok (pageviews tracking, visits, etc.) but campaigns tracking.

We recently created a link with all the utm_* required parameters (`utm_source`, `utm_medium` and `utm_campaign`) pointing to the Chrome Store landing page but Google Analytics is not showing all the clicks in Traffic Sources > Campaigns section. As an example, in a certain day we know that the link had been clicked more than 200 times and Google Analytics only show 14 visits under the created Campaign.

I ensured than there's no redirect that loses the parameters making a `curl --head` and the response is a `200 OK`.

Anyone who is developing a Chrome Extension and using Google Analytics to track campaigns did have the same problem?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking with Joe Marini (Developer Advocate / Chrome Apps, Extensions, Web Store), he told me that right now, the Google Chrome Web Store "don't yet have the ability to report that data".

For more information, take a look to this thread in Chromium Apps Google Group:

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/chromium-apps/ageceM5IVj0/W4c-TGrkXBIJ